# Реализация шаблона Friend функции потока вывода

Tags: c++

```
<Heder.h>   
//объявление
friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &, matrix<T> &);
//реализация 
template<typename T>
 ostream& operator << (ostream &os, matrix<T> &obj)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < obj.col; j++)
            os << setw(4) << obj.p[i][j];
        os << endl;
    }
    os << endl;

    return os;
}
```

Ошибка:

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream > &,class matrix &)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот [тут](http://web.mst.edu/~nmjxv3/articles/templates.html) есть примеры как реализовать то, что вам нужно. Это первая ссылка которая гуглится по запросу "friend function for template class c++"

Вариант 1:

```
template<typename T>
class matrix
{
public:
    // ...
    template<typename T2>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const matrix<T2>& obj);
    // ...
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const matrix<T>& obj)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < obj.col; j++)
            os << setw(4) << obj.p[i][j];
        os << endl;
    }
    os << endl;

    return os;
}
```

Вариант 2:

```
template<typename T>
class matrix
{
public:
    // ...
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const matrix& obj)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < obj.col; j++)
                os << setw(4) << obj.p[i][j];
            os << endl;
        }
        os << endl;

        return os;
    }
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Ответы ссылками не приветствуются. Будьте добры предоставить полноценное решение.

Comment: По такому оформлению вопроса надо было вообще одну ссылку оставить без комментариев (сейчас напишу..)

Comment: качество ответа не должно страдать, от качества вопроса. Ссылку можно отправить комментарием или вообще пройти мимо. Всё таки ответ подразумевает решение проблемы, а ответ-ссылка на SO запрещён правилами

Comment: Спасибо,за оформление прошу прощение.

Comment: @AleksandrFursenko, если ответ устраивает, то отметьте его галочкой